# _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync throws exception in net core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to use User manager in .NET Core 3.1 but this code:

```
    public async Task<bool> CheckPassword(User user, string password)
    {
        var appUser = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(user);

        return await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(appUser, password);
    }
```

throws this exception:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters

Stack trace:

> at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>      at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher`1.VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, String hashedPassword, String providedPassword)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`

It's weird because same code with same hash in database in .Net Core 2 works well.
Any ideas where is the problem?

Edit:

I found this file: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e276c8174b8bfdeb70efceafa81c75f8badbc8db/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs

and it looks like the problem is here:

```
 public virtual PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (hashedPassword == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hashedPassword));
        }
        if (providedPassword == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providedPassword));
        }

        byte[] decodedHashedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
```

But i tried to validate hash in database by https://base64.guru/tools/validator and its Ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either saved hashed password or need to override the CheckPassword method for checking manually.

By default, the system checks the hashed password and you are passing plain text.

Comment: But it looks like the problem appears when PasswordHasher is trying to encode encoded string from database table.  And this hash was created by UserManager when was creating user.

Comment: So, the column in the database has an appropriate size to cooperate with the encoded string of passwords? I think the password you are saving in the database is truncated. Can you verify it?
It might be one reason.

Comment: In database is this string: "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEC+6mW3Rp8RvJsXGCfNtWBhZKuI5K8fCdRKL1f7wuzPqMpmxlYE84PYcMCbXZnONsg==" , and its valid Base64 string.

Comment: How are you creating _userManger object? Can you share the snippet?

Comment: In startup im configuring it like this: https://imgur.com/VYC4Z2a, and then through DI